# LocalStorage in Phonegap across different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I'm trying to use a simple string stored in the localStorage functionality built into phonegap as a simple setting to deicide witch set of data to fetch from a server. In the index.html I've been able to save a string from a `<select>` menu and display it in the header. Using this javascript code:

```
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            window.onload = function() {
                document.getElementById("BtnStore").addEventListener("click", storeData, false);
                $("#headertitle").append(loadData()).headertitle("refresh");
            }

            function storeData() {
                var e = document.getElementById("klass");
                var klass = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                localStorage.setItem("klass", klass);

                window.location.href = "index.html";
            }



            function loadData() {
                var getKlass = localStorage.getItem("klass");
                return getKlass;
            }


            </script>
```

This appends the stored value in an `<h1>` element.

But when I from a different html page try to reference the same key from the localstore, nothing is being displayed. Here is that code:

```
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            function onDeviceReady() {
                $("#hejsan").append(loadData()).hejsan("refresh");
            };


            function loadData() {
                var getKlass = localStorage.getItem("klass");
                return getKlass;
            }


            </script>
```

This is also just as a test, appending the string to a `<p>` element. For some reason nothing is happening, someone knows why?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried doing your storage procedure in an on deviceready callback?

Comment: No I haven't, do you got a suggestion of how to do that? :)

Comment: Actually, I think it's more complex than that. Is this working outside of phonegap?

Comment: I would be inclined to check you console/logcat since I'm not sure what those refresh calls are trying to do.

Comment: try adding an alert to `loadData`

Comment: The localstorage isn't a phonegap only technology, it does work in a web browser, if that is what your'e asking? Though not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I suggest an `alert` or `console.log` in `loadData()` to ensure the data is being loaded

Comment: I modified the loadData function into this:
`function loadData() {
    var getKlass = localStorage.getItem("klass");
    return getKlass;
    alert('data is loaded');
}`
And you're right the function isn't being called, I used the refresh commands because previously when I used append it just wouldn't work without it

Comment: check the console for general errors

Comment: I get this error in the console when loading the index page (which does work though):
"TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#headertitle").append(loadData()).headertitle("refresh")')"

Comment: Should I use something like innerHTML instead?

Comment: Not in jquery you shouldn't. You should use `.html()` or a function of it.

Comment: so just replace .append with .html ?

Comment: works great in the index view still, and the error is gone - but still not working in the second page

Comment: is loadData being called?

Comment: no, but I started from the ground up and called the function directly, like this:
`function loadData() {
var getKlass = localStorage.getItem("klass");
alert(getKlass);
}
loadData();`
And it returned the correct string

Comment: Then something else is going wrong. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to make it work, here is the code i used:

**First page:**

```
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

            window.onload = function() {
                document.getElementById("BtnStore").addEventListener("click", storeData, false);
                $("#headertitle").html(loadData()).headertitle;
            }

            function storeData() {
                //localStorage.clear();
                var e = document.getElementById("klass");
                var klass = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
                localStorage.setItem("klass", klass);

                window.location.href = "index.html";
            }



            function loadData() {
                var getKlass = localStorage.getItem("klass");
                return getKlass;
            }


            </script>
```

**Second page:**

```
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    function loadData() {
                        var getKlass = localStorage.getItem("klass");
                        $("#hejsan").html(getKlass).hejsan;
                    }
                    loadData();
                }
```

If anyone else gets stuck! :)